# How to validate Form and display the validation message using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

I need to validate my form fields and display them using tool Tip  using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

> index.php:

```
<form name="billdata" id="billdata"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px"> Name :</span>
<input type="text" name="u_name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Add Catagory">
</div> 
<span class="error" id="nameError" style="display:none;">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
 <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Email :</span>
<input type="email" name="u_email" id="emailid" class="form-control" placeholder="Add Email Id">
</div>
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Mobile No :</span>
<input type="text" name="u_mobile_no" id="mobno" class="form-control" placeholder="Add Mobile No">
 </div>
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">TYPE OF COMPLAINT
 :</span>
<select class="form-control"  id="compleant">
<option value="">Select types of complaint</option>
<option value="card">Card Related</option>
<option value="claim">Claim Related</option>
<option value="product">Product Related</option>
<option value="Premimum">Premimum Related</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Upload Image :</span>

 <input type="file" class="filestyle form-control" data-size="lg" name="uploadme" id="bannerimage">
</div>
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 text-right col-md-12" style="display:none;">
<img src="" name="pro" border="0" style="width:50px; height:50px; border:#808080 1px solid;" />
</div>
 <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="complainSubmit"  id="addProfileData" value="Add"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['complainSubmit']) || isset($_REQUEST['appsubmit']))
{
        $name=$_REQUEST['u_name'];


}
?>
```

In the above code i need when user will click on `Add` button  the fields will be checked for empty, email format and image format.The validation message should display in `tooltip`.When all validation will success the all field value can collect and submit.Please help me.

Comment: Check this link http://thrilleratplay.github.io/jquery-validation-bootstrap-tooltip/

Answer (score 0):

Nobody will write any validation for you. However you can check some libraries that ppl already made, such as **parsley** at http://parsleyjs.org/ . It is a great validator for web forms and such